# Why is this SQL SUM statement correct?

Tags: sql, sum

In my schema, I have a table Projects, and a table Tasks.  Each project is comprised of tasks.  Each task has Hours and PercentComplete.

Example table:

```
ProjectID    TaskID    Hours   PercentComplete
1            1         100     50
1            2         120     80
```

I am trying to get the weighted percentage complete for the project.  I am doing this using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, SUM(T.Hours) AS Hours, 
SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours) / 100 AS CompleteHours, 
SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours) / SUM(T.Hours) AS PercentComplete
FROM Projects AS P INNER JOIN
        Tasks AS T ON T.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
WHERE     (P.ProjectID = 1)
```

My question is about this part of that statement:

```
SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours) / SUM(T.Hours) AS PercentComplete
```

This gives me the correct weighted percentage for this project (in the case of the sample data above, 66%).  But I cannot seem to wrap my head around why it does this.

Why does this query work?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? How would you have attempted to write this query?

Comment: I wrote this query.  I just don't know why it gives me the correct results.

Comment: Look out for integer math in this. Do you really want the rounding you will get instead of the accurate numbers?

Comment: One hopes the Hours column is constrained to be non-zero...

Comment: @Matthew: "I just don't know why it gives me the correct results." Good guesswork, then!

Comment: +1 for wanting to know why it works even though it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours) / 100` is the number of complete hours.
- `SUM(T.Hours)` is the total number of hours.
- The ratio of these two amounts, i.e.:

  ```
  (SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours) / 100) / SUM(T.Hours)
  ```

  is the proportion of hours complete (it should be between 0 and 1).
- Multiplying this by 100 gives the percentage.

I prefer to keep percentages like this out of the database and move them to the presentation layer. It would be much easier if the database stored "hours completed" and "hours total" and did not store the percentages at all. The extra factors of 100 in the calculations confuse the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are finding the number of hours completed over the number of hours total.

`SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours)` computes the total number of hours that you have completed.  `(100 * 50) = 50 * 100 + (120 * 80) = 146 * 100` is the numerator.  `146` hours have been completed on this job, and we keep a `100` multiplier for the percent (because it is `[0-100]` instead of `[0-1]`)

Then we find the total number of hours worked, `SUM(T.Hours)`, which is `100 + 120 = 220`.

Then dividing, we find the weighted average. `(146 * 100) / 220 = 0.663636364 * 100 = 66.4%`

Is this what you were wondering about?

Answer (score 1):

It calculates the two sums individually by adding up the value for each row then divides them at the end

SUM(T.PercentComplete * T.Hours)

```
50*  100 +
80 * 120
-------
14,600
```

SUM(T.Hours)

```
100 +
120
---
220
```

Then the division at the end

```
14,600 / 220
------------
66.3636
```

**Edit** As per HLGEM's comment it will actually return 66 due to integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions, such as SUM(), work against the set of data defined by the GROUP BY clause.  So if you group by ProjectID, ProjectName, the functions will break things down by that.

Answer (score 0):

The SUM peratiorn first multiply the columns than add

```
( 100* 50+ 120* 80)  / (100+ 120)
```